# SpringCloud Gateway request processing for service to service calls

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

We have three services A, B, C and all of them are configured on Cloud Gateway. Below is their communication pattern.

UI-->A-->B-->C

We have used GlobalFilter and the filter logic is as below.

```
public class CustomGlobalFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange) {

       return filterChain.filter(exchange.mutate(). 
request(updatedrequest).build()).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {

          log.info("Request processing complete for {}", request.getPath());

          }
     }

 @Override
 public int getOrder() {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

We are facing an issue where we are not seeing the INFO logger for the first service (A) after all the requests are completed. We see the logger for B and C. In other words, the control is not properly ending with the GlobalFilter. Is it an issue with the way I configured the filter above using `fromRunnable()`?

Are there any best practices for implementing service to service calls for filter logic that I mentioned above?

Comment: so the UI calls your Gateway (G), which calls A, which calls G to route to B which calls, G to route to C? Is that correct? Just trying to understand the routing or is it UI > Gateway > A > B > C

Comment: Ideally it is like this :: UI > Gateway > A >Gateway > B > Gateway > C. Basically all the service communication is through Gateway.

Comment: @Darren Forsythe, any clue on this?